# Can Angular JS be the replacement for template engines like EJS or Jade?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to MEAN stack. I have seen Template engines being used while developing node JS apps and realized it can be used to make static documents dynamic by integrating values from server.

However, I see Angular JS facilitates same stuff. Then why use template engines ? Is it absolutely necessary to use them? Can angular completely replace them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track simi. When starting with Angular it is tempting to do "double templating" - templating on the server side and on the client side. Unless you absolutely need the server to render HTML your server should just be an API, the usual REST services serving JSON. Expose an API and treat your Angular application like any other client (Android, iOS). To see an example of this approach in action check out the [Angular Fullstack Yeoman generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

There are valid reasons to want the server to render full HTML responses, SEO probably being the most common. Whether or not it is worth the extra effort is a design decision.

Comment: Thank you for introducing the term server side templating and client side templating. Explained everything . Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

As with all questions that are "this" or "that" the answer is "it depends".

First of all they aren't exclusive, so there isn't a reason to choose between them, but you should try to use them in a predictable way in your code base

Server side templates are good because it's generally less complex and it reduces client compute costs. If a part of your page doesn't need to be dynamic on the client side, it's a good candidate for EJS. An example might be a dynamic menu in a CRM application where you'll only change the content with config updates.

Angular (and other client-side MVW frameworks) offer lots of great things really. The first immediate benefit is that you can easily load dynamic content on the client side, which can result in better responsiveness and reduce the complexity of the backend (assuming you already needed an API layer, you can get a lot of stuff for free). A good example would be an auto-refreshing homepage feed which reloading the whole page is a waste. But most of that we've had for a long time with AJAX. Angular also makes it easy to generate the template so you can, once again, write less code and (if done right) more readable, testable code.

I think the right answer is to use both as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

NO. Angularjs cannot be the replacement for template engine like EJS or Jade. You need to use any one of the template engine. If you like ejs templating engine then you may use your angularjs code inside that template. Just suppose this is your regular html and you're including angularjs in it.

Comment: Then what purpose if EJS serving in that case is my question.

Comment: You should know if you know to use template engine which performs such as routing...

Comment: Routing I believe is very well performed by Express ?Isn't it ?

Comment: yes, exactly. you should learn about them if you don't know.